# Save edited data in ckeditor to html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ckeditor

I am using Ajax success function to load the content of html file to CKeditor

```
function getTextInfo(fileUrl) {
          $.ajax({
              url: fileUrl,
              success: function (data){
              document.getElementById("myform").value = data;
        }
          });
}
```

and this is the script to call getTextInfo()

```
<script type="text/javascript">                     
          $(document).ready(function(){
          getTextInfo(filePath);
          });
</script>
```

and this is the script to load CKeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
          CKEDITOR.replace( 'myform', {
          fullPage: true,
          allowedContent: true,
          extraPlugins: 'wysiwygarea'
          })
 </script>
```

I need some way to save edited data from editor to html file.
very thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blob for that. Note I used template string only for multi line string, other than that it is es5.

```js
var someHTML = `
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Some html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Some Html</h1>
  </body>
</html>`;

var blob = new Blob([someHTML], {type : 'text/html'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="'+ url + '" download="some.html">download</a>';
```